# why is my login activity crashing when I run my project?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I am fairly new to android studio and when I try to run my project the app gets crashed for some reason and I can't seem to figure out as to what is the problem that has occurred. If I give anything apart from login activity as my starting activity then it loading correctly.

Here is my java code:

```
package com.example.hireme2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t;
    AppCompatButton b;
    EditText email,password;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_login);
        mAuth=(FirebaseAuth) FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign);
        b=(AppCompatButton)findViewById(R.id.login);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.log_email);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.log_password);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),signup.class));
            }
        });
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String e,p;
                e=String.valueOf(email.getText());
                p=String.valueOf(password.getText());
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(p)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(e,p)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login success.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F3E1"
    tools:context=".login">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="scroll">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/top_login" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:textColor="#6C5DD2"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="40dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="EMAIL"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#6C5DD2"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/log_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edt"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="enter your email"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textColorHint="#707070"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PASSWORD"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#6C5DD2"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/log_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edt"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="enter your password"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textColorHint="#707070"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#707070"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="OR"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#707070"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/google" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/linked" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sign"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Don't have an account ? Signup"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:textColor="#6C5DD2"
                android:clickable="true" />
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is what it's showing after running the project:

```
03/12 00:58:17: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 XL API 31.
Install successfully finished in 317 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.hireme2/com.example.hireme2.signup" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25979 on device 'Pixel_4_XL_API_31 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10150; state: ENABLED
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.hireme2' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
D/AppCompatDelegate: Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
W/example.hireme: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/example.hireme: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10150; state: ENABLED
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x770750959250, tid 26027
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x770750959f10: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x770750959f10: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x770972f69080) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x770750967650, tid 26027
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3e3ffe000 size 0x2000
W/Gralloc4: allocator 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=479.38ms min=27.09ms max=1300.56ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=529.13ms min=49.32ms max=1483.89ms count=3
```

Comment: What exactly do you call a crash in all those lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized firebase sdk like this:

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

And also please provide a full error log of exceptions.because current log which you shared there are no any crash log.

Comment: No I had just given it in the dependencies while implementing the firebase. But now what did worked out for me was that I gave the signed out method outside the Oncreate class of every activity and somehow it worked out for me. I honestly don't know how though.

Comment: @CHETANSR if you use firebase in your project you must initialize first in your base activity or launcher activity